# 5V stepboost low voltage

Tags: boost, 5v

i have two 5V stepboost modules from Ebay, however they are quite poor. Blue can provide atleast 1.45W, but the green one, is the worst - can provide only 0.09W, and i noticed, after two minutes battery was hot, and the cables were hot too, so there is some kind of very high current drain from battery, with the green module.

[image: Green module]

[image]

Is there any way to upgrade these modules to give me atleast 5V/500mA ? Or its waste of time, trying to repair these cheap modules ?

Thank you !

//load on output was USB Xiaomi powerbank (charging current can be up to 1.8A)

//input current of green module was 1.5A (lol, now i know why the battery was hot)
input current of blue module was 0.56A

//as power source i used 1000mAh li-ion battery

Comment: It is a waste if time.

Comment: "load on output was USB Xiaomi powerbank (charging current can be up to 1.8A)" How do you know that was a valid (i.e. within specification) load for those boost regulators? Please supply the specifications for those boost regulators, for further analysis.

Comment: Sorry, only info from seller, was: 5V/1A mobile booster for li ion battery. Nothing more. I was just curious, if i can make it work better somehow, but looks like, i can't :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 5V/1A mobile booster for li ion battery.

but...

> load on output was USB Xiaomi powerbank (charging current can be up to 1.8A)

so you are exceeding the specification and, considering the cheap designs of those modules, *anything* could happen. Moral - stay within specifications!

Having said that, those are cheap & simple circuits, and I wouldn't spend time trying to increase the output current from one of those, as you ask. Instead buy (or build) one which is designed for a higher output current in the first place (while staying within the limits of your input power source).

Comment: OK guys, these modules are just s**t. Its better idea to buy USB powerbank and remove that module from case - or don't be like me and don't buy cheap modules :D

Answer (score 1):

Buy cheap crap, get cheap crap. The issue could be counterfeit/fake ICs, bad caps, mislabeled inductor, a short on the board, etc.

The blue one is supposedly supposed to be able to put out up to 200mA~300mA @ 5V from a single AA. 500mA~600mA from 2x AA. To get 500mA @ 5V = 2.5W, plus a (generous) 15% efficiency so 2.87W from 3V, or 0.96 Amps out. Given the info on the blue one's draw, the main issue is that it's not outputting 5V, so the power bank is drawing less. 3V * 0.56A = 1.68W, minus 15% efficiency, is 1.428 Watts, close enough to what the meter reads.

The green one is plainly broken, as 3V * 1.5A = 4.5 Watts input, but 0.1 Watt output? Where is the other 4.4 Watts going? Wasted in heat no doubt.

Comment: thank you for reply, i forgot to mention, i used one li-ion 1000mAh battery. So there is no way (easy way) to get little more higher voltage ?

Comment: @user2945696 a Li-Ion at 3.7V nominal, the numbers don't change much from the 2x AA 3.0V I used. The issue is the green one is broken, and the blue one is out of spec (not putting out 5V)

Comment: @Passerby - Hi - Are you sure the green one is broken, and not that it's behaviour is due to the excessive output load, which is outside its specification? In my testing (years ago) on some random boost modules from Ebay, using a variable load and lab PSU as input, I saw similar anomalous behaviour from some when I exceeded the specified output current (or, sometimes, starting slightly below the specification).

Comment: @SamGibson if it's current limiting itself, then the input would also see a lower current. 4.4 Watts of power doesn't just disappear.

Comment: @Passerby - Agreed that the observed behaviour isn't as simple as current limiting, but I'm not as confident as you to call it faulty, when it's being operated outside its specification. Anyway, thanks for your thoughts. :-) [I notice that the green module doesn't have a large output capacitor on the visible side of the PCB, unlike the blue module which does. So if the green module doesn't have one at all, it does look horribly cheap!]